Console login service(s) cannot run while trying to emulate Solaris 11.4 on FreeBSD operating system version 14.1
I’m trying to boot Solaris 11.04 using qemu or UEFI on the FreeBSD operating system version 14.1, using the following parameters:
qemu-system-x86_64 -name guest=s11x64,debug-threads=on \
-machine pc,usb=off \
-cpu kvm64,hv_relaxed,hv_time,hv_synic \
-m 8G -smp 2,sockets=2,cores=1,threads=1 -nodefaults -no-shutdown \
-drive file=/bhyve/Files/ISO/sol-11_4-text-x86.iso,format=raw \
-drive file=/mnt/zroot2/zroot2/bhyve/img/Solaris/solaris114.img,format=raw \
-global PIIX4_PM.disable_s3=1 \
-global PIIX4_PM.disable_s4=1 \
-device ich9-usb-ehci1,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4.0x7 \
-device ich9-usb-uhci1,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=0,bus=pci.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x4 \
-device ich9-usb-uhci2,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4.0x1 \
-device ich9-usb-uhci3,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=4,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4.0x2 \
-device VGA,id=video0,vgamem_mb=32,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 \
-netdev tap,id=mynet0,ifname=tap4,script=no,downscript=no \
-device e1000,netdev=mynet0,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:01 \
-device ich9-ahci,id=sata \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly=on,file=/usr/local/share/edk2-qemu/QEMU_UEFI_CODE-x86_64.fd \

As you can see below, it almost worked, but not yet. I think only a few parameters are missing:
SunOS Release 5.11 Version 11.4.0.15.0 64‐bit
Copyright (c) 1983, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Remounting root read/write
Probing for device nodes ...
Preparing image for use
Unable to mount media
Requesting System Maintenance Mode
(See /lib/svc/share/README for more information.)
Console login service(s) cannot run

Enter user name for system maintenance (control‑d to bypass): █

While it fully worked using BIOS instead of UEFI:
/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
-L /usr/local/share/qemu/ -name guest=s11x64,debug-threads=on \
-machine pc,usb=off -cpu kvm64,hv_relaxed,hv_time,hv_synic \
-m 8192 -smp 2,sockets=2,cores=1,threads=1 \
-nodefaults -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=delay -no-shutdown \
-global PIIX4_PM.disable_s3=1 \
-global PIIX4_PM.disable_s4=1 -boot strict=on \
-device ich9-usb-ehci1,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4.0x7 \
-device ich9-usb-uhci1,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=0,bus=pci.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x4 \
-device ich9-usb-uhci2,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4.0x1 \
-device ich9-usb-uhci3,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=4,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4.0x2 \
-device VGA,id=video0,vgamem_mb=32,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 \
-hda /mnt/zroot2/zroot2/bhyve/img/Solaris/solaris114.img \
-boot d --cdrom /bhyve/Files/ISO/sol-11_4-text-x86.iso \
-netdev tap,id=mynet0,ifname=tap3,script=no,downscript=no \
-device e1000,netdev=mynet0,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:01 \

SunOS Release 5.11 Version 11.4.0.15.0 64‐bit
Copyright (c) 1983, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Remounting root read/write
Probing for device nodes ...
Preparing image for use
Done mounting image
USB keyboard
 1. Arabic                        15. Korean
 2. Belgian                       16. Latin‐American
 3. Brazilian                     17. Norwegian
 4. Canadian‐Bilingual            18. Portuguese
 5. Canadian‐French               19. Russian
 6. Danish                        20. Spanish
 7. Dutch                         21. Swedish
 8. Dvorak                        22. Swiss‐French
 9. Finnish                       23. Swiss‐German
10. French                        24. Traditional‐Chinese
11. German                        25. TurkishQ
12. Italian                       26. UK‑English
13. Japanese‐type6                27. US‑English
14. Japanese
To select the keyboard layout, enter a number [default 27]:█


have you played it if= for the -drive that specifies the .img image?

In the first case, you're not adding the iso file as a cdrom

@MarcusMüller : can you elaborate more ?

replace -drive file=/mnt/zroot2/zroot2/bhyve/img/Solaris/solaris114.img,format=raw with -drive if=pflash,file=/mnt/zroot2/zroot2/bhyve/img/Solaris/solaris114.img,format=raw, or if=ide, scsi, sd or mtd

it didn't work : https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/GhMQCYKc9b/

@StéphaneChazelas : please elaborate more. Take in consideration that -boot d --cdrom /bhyve/Files/ISO/sol-11_4-text-x86.iso IS not compatible with : -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly=on,file=/usr/local/share/edk2-qemu/QEMU_UEFI_CODE-x86_64.fd \

@Marietto same for ide and scsi instead of pflash? surprised.

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/KWNmQrwFCM/


It's hard to tell what conclusion/information your last pastebin is trying to communicate, just that the final output of your command is = ? 2) While I don't think it is an issue, I would remove the final backslash character (it might be throwing something off).

